# How to comment (reply to) all comments (address all commentators) under one question/answer?

Tags: discussion

I know that with '@name' I can address one user, and that any comment is indicated to the author of the question/answer.

But is it possible to address  a comment to all participants to a series of comments under one question or answer?

Comment: I do you @mods from time to time. That could be an unofficial way to explain a flag or say that a particular user is ranting all over the place or whatever (anything which does not fit the flag). The mods can easily search for @ mods. @ mods let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: @Private - in fact i was just interested in giving a piece of information, a conclusion, to different users that had been involved in a discussion related to a solution to which they all had brought a contribution. commenting for each of them would have added more comments to a list that was already too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a related feature request as MSO which has been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). So there's not much hope of it getting implemented in near future.

- [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

Some of the suggestions from that question:

- Post multiple comments, notifying one person each in them.
- Read [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) The author of the post always get notified, so we do not need to use `@` before their name, just adding their name and if necessary, highlighting it using bold/italics to get their attention would be sufficient.